# Troubles with updating BLOB on Mysql for thumbnail

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update and  insert a created thumbnail into a MYSQL BLOB.

I have tried almost anything but can not get it to insert the created picture to the Database.

```
function update($email)
{
  if(file_exists("$email.jpg"))
  {
    $image = "$email.jpg";
    $tbl = 'tpctmembers';
    $query1 = "SELECT image FROM $tbl WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = queryMysql($query1);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($rows > 0)
    {
      $query2 = "UPDATE $tbl SET image ='$image' WHERE email ='$email'";
      queryMysql($query2);
    }
    else
    {
      $query3 = "INSERT into $tbl(image) VALUES('$image') where email = '$email'";
      queryMysql($query3);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank You !

Comment: As above, saving the image file name doesn't look lik ewhat you want to do here, also "$email.jpg" is a bit odd, the inserted data will simply be the email address with .jpg appended on the end???

Comment: So in in this case, once the the thumbnail is created, what would be the best way to store it??? Upload to the jpeg to the Database? Thank you

Comment: You might very well be better of storing the image on disk and the path/filename to the image in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the image file, and insert that data, not the string naming the file. See [this tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/6937-tutorial-storing-images-mysql-php.html).